# Search String contain specific text in column and return result from the same row of another column

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way in excel formula instead of vba script to search for specific text in a column and return result from the same row of another column. If this can't be done in formula, how this done in VBA?

Example:

```
(Column A) Hostname
UK-Aaron-01
UK-Bob-01
UK-AaronOoi
UK-XP-Peter
UK-XP-Jack
UK-Brandon

(Column B) Hostname Department
==This will be the place where the result would be


(Column C) User
Aaron
Acciai
Achilles
Acton
AaronOoi
Adarsh
Aba
Abbas
Bob
Abeeku
Abhay
Abner
Absolom
Peter
Acoose
Adagio
Brandon


(Column D) Department
Marketing
IT
Sales
HR
Marketing
IT
HR
arketing
Sales
HR
Marketing
IT
HR
Marketing
IT
Sales

The result in (Column B) should be:
Marketing
Marketing
IT,HR (If UK-AaronOoi match 2 names "Aaron" & "AaronOOi" then it will be separated with coma) 
HR
NotFound (If no match then return not found)
Sales
```

The hostname,User & department contain data more than 4k

Comment: [VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally able to work on the solution with simple guideline from toufikovich and additional Google for the rest of the answer. This is my first time doing VBA script and it was hard to start with so excuse if it looks newbie :)

```
Private Sub Run()

Dim lastRowB As Integer
Dim lastRowC As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get Row last number in A with data
End With

With ActiveSheet
    lastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Get Row last number in C with data
End With

For k = 2 To lastRowB: 'Run a loop for each hostname in Column B
     For i = 2 To lastRowC: 'Run a lopp for each user in column C
        If Cells(k, 1).Value Like "*" & Cells(i, 3).Value & "*" Then 'Check if Cell in A is like Cell in C with wildchard
            Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 2).Value & "," & Cells(i, 4).Value 'Check if there is more than 1 similar User match saperate them by coma ","
            If Left(Cells(k, 2).Value, 1) = "," Then ' If the string start with coma ","
                Cells(k, 2).Value = Right(Cells(k, 2).Value, Len(Cells(k, 2).Value) - 1) ' Then remove the first text
            End If
        End If
     Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it's toufikovich... glad you solved it. for the number of the last row in a column you ca use the following : `dim l as long` then `l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`... cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the guide - toufikovich

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, in VBA you can do this, but i have minimized the hypothesis in order to make it more simple:

suppose you only have in raw A:

1. UK-Aaron-01
2. UK-Bob-01
3. UK-AaronOoi

the VBA code will be like this:

```
Sub find_department_by_name()
 Dim i As Integer
 For i = 1 To 3:
    If Cells(i, 1).value Like "*-Aaron-*" Then
        Cells(i, 2).value = "Marketing"
    Else:
        Cells(i, 2).value = "Not Found"
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

when you run it you will have in column B:

1. Marketing
2. Not Found
3. Not Found

i hope this is what you are looking for (of course you need to customize it to your needs)

Comment: Could we do search in Column instead of hard code "*-Aaron-*". Then when found it need to return the result offset right to 1

Comment: yes but as i said you need to work on the code a bit to suite you, for example you can iterate in column c for the user in stead of hard coding it so it might be `if cells(i,1).value like "*-" & cells(i,3) & "-*" then` do something

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be:

```
vlookup = vlookup("*desiredtextstring*",a1:a11,1,0)
```

Alternatively, to return desired text spread across you can replace `vlookup` with `hlookup`